# Filter with GROUP BY and CASE pr IF or IF EXIST

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

1.0. I have a table like this:

```
    COD     CICLE   SCORE DATE  

    020003931   XVIII   16  Dieciseis   13/03/08    
    020003931   VIII    17  Decisiete   13/03/08    
    020003931   II  18  Dieciocho   13/03/08    
    020003931   IX  15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   III 16  Dieciseis   13/03/08    
    020003931   XI  15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   IV  16  Dieciseis   13/03/08    
    020003931   XII 15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   VI  18  Dieciocho   13/03/08    
    020003931   XIII    15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   V   18  Dieciocho   13/03/08    
    020003931   XIV 16  Dieciseis   13/03/08    

    020003931   VI  18  Dieciocho   13/03/08    
    020003931   XV  17  Decisiete   13/03/08    
    020003931   VI  17  Decisiete   13/03/08    
    020003931   VII 15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   XVI 16  Dieciseis   13/03/08    
    020003931   V   16  Dieciseis   13/04/08    
    020003931   XVI 16  Dieciseis   06/04/10

    020003931   XV  16  Dieciseis   01/09/10    
    020003931   XVI 18  Dieciocho   05/10/10    
    020003931   XVII    18  Dieciocho   03/11/10    
    020003931   XVIII   17  Decisiete   31/01/11    
    020003931   XIX 16  Dieciseis   03/03/11    
    020003931   XX  17  Decisiete   04/04/11    
    020003931   XXI 15  Quince  09/05/11    
    020003931   XXII    16  Dieciseis   06/06/11    
    020003931   XXIII   17  Decisiete   08/08/11    
    020003931   XXIV    15  Quince  13/09/11
```

1.1. the review of duplicates is:

```
    V 2
    VI 3
    XV 2
    XVI 3
    XVIII 2
```

2.0. I need a new table without duplicated records and taking values of the most recent cicle ordered by date (only one), like this:

```
    COD     CICLE   SCORE DATE
    020003931   II  18  Dieciocho   13/03/08    
    020003931   III 16  Dieciseis   13/03/08    
    020003931   IV  16  Dieciseis   13/03/08    
    020003931   V   16  Dieciseis   13/04/08    
    020003931   VI  18  Dieciocho   13/03/08    
    020003931   VII 15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   VIII    17  Decisiete   13/03/08    
    020003931   IX  15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   XI  15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   XII 15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   XIII    15  Quince  13/03/08    
    020003931   XIV 16  Dieciseis   13/03/08    
    020003931   XV  16  Dieciseis   01/09/10    
    020003931   XVI 18  Dieciocho   05/10/10    
    020003931   XVII    18  Dieciocho   03/11/10    
    020003931   XVIII   17  Decisiete   31/01/11    
    020003931   XIX 16  Dieciseis   03/03/11    
    020003931   XX  17  Decisiete   04/04/11    
    020003931   XXI 15  Quince  09/05/11    
    020003931   XXII    16  Dieciseis   06/06/11    
    020003931   XXIII   17  Decisiete   08/08/11    
    020003931   XXIV    15  Quince  13/09/11
```

at the moment I have this code:

```
IF EXISTS(
        SELECT CICLO, count(CICLO) FROM CI_MATRICULA
                where codigo ='020003931' and idioma='003' and nota>15
                GROUP BY CICLO
                HAVING count(CICLO) > 1)
BEGIN
   --SELECT MAX(fecha) from ci_matricula where codigo ='020003931' and idioma='003' and nota>15
END
```

I've tried to make a query with IF INTO IF (for run cicle I INTO II AND INTO III... Until XXV without success.

Also I've tried with "CASE" but I think not is a good idea for the indexed information, I need another alternatives or solution please.

PS: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v 13.0

Comment: FYI your version of SSMS has nothing to do with  your version of SQL Server. I assume by SSMS v 13.0 you mean build version 13, which was SSMS 2016. What we really need is your version of SQL Server, which you can get with `PRINT @@VERSION;`.

Answer (score 1):

The window function `ROW_NUMBER` can be used to calculate a sequential number over a partition.

Then by taking only the first, the dups are filtered out.

```
WITH CTE_MATRICULA AS
(
    SELECT COD, CICLE, SCORE, [DATE]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COD, CICLE ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS RN
    FROM CI_MATRICULA
)
SELECT COD, CICLE, SCORE, [DATE]
INTO #TEMP_MATRICULA
FROM CTE_MATRICULA
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, works, but i had a problem ordering dates

021703505     IV      16          01/09/17
021703505     IX      16          05/05/18
021703505     V       15          03/11/17

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is that `Date` column perhaps a `VARCHAR(8)` that has them in a "dd/MM/yy" format?  Then the ROW_NUMBER should order them as [converted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) to a `DATE`.  F.e. `ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,[Date],3)`.  It's always best to store date/time data in a data type designed for them.

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer using window functions (See @LukStorms answer). You could also use a Correlated Subquery to do this:

```
SELECT  COD, CICLE, SCORE, [DATE]
FROM CI_MATRICULA matr
WHERE [DATE]=(SELECT max([DATE]) FROM CI_MATRICULA WHERE matr.CICLE = CICLE);
```

Unlike the window-function option, this will still produce duplicates if multiple `CICLE` occur on the same `max([DATE])`. The window-function version will pick one somewhat randomly.